# Azure Active Directory and WCF authentication

Tags: wcf, azure, adfs2.0, azure-active-directory

I have WCF service and I need to secure it with Azure Active Directory.
I've already read all related questions here and at social.msdn but still can't get my sample working.
I want authentication to work in following way.

1. No any popups displayed when user calls WCF service from client.
2. User passes username/password and receives auth token from Azure ADFS
3. Then in application (let it be console app for now) we open channel via Create `CreateChannelWithIssuedToken` method and all subsequent calls are made with the token we get from AAD.

What I'm doing and what my problems are.
I'm for now using VS 2012 and Identity and Access tool to generate proper config file for the WCF service.
So my service has following address. `http://localhost:1785/Service1.svc`

I go to azure portal and create new Web application with name `http://localhost:1785/Service1.svc`, sign on url `http://localhost:1785/Service1.svc` and app id url `http://localhost:1785/Service1.svc`

Then I check endpoints of the application and copy federation metadata which looks as
`https://login.windows.net/{some guid}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml`

Using Identity and Access tools I add WAAD Identity provider to the Service project.
My web.config file looks as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://login.windows.net/34bb8966-5537-4b1b-85ed-f501a06c1225/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="productionSTS" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true">
            <!--Certificate added by Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio.-->
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" />
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message>
              <issuerMetadata address="https://login.windows.net/adfs/services/trust/mex" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost:1785/Service1.svc" />
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="https://sts.windows.net/34bb8966-5537-4b1b-85ed-f501a06c1225/">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="92B88C3DD981BF1EBCB244FCFA63C007706C79E0" />
            <add thumbprint="3270BF5597004DF339A4E62224731B6BD82810A6" />
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="https://sts.windows.net/34bb8966-5537-4b1b-85ed-f501a06c1225/" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <!--certificationValidationMode set to "None" by the the Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio. For development purposes.-->
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

Then I created console application and added service reference to the service project.
After adding reference, config looks as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService1">
                    <security>
                        <message>
                            <!--<issuer address="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2005/12/ServiceModel/Addressing/Anonymous" />-->
                          <issuer address="https://login.windows.net/34bb8966-5537-4b1b-85ed-f501a06c1225/wsfed" binding="ws2007HttpBinding"/>
                          <issuerMetadata address="https://login.windows.net/adfs/services/trust/mex" />
                            <tokenRequestParameters>
                                <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                                    <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/SymmetricKey</trust:KeyType>
                                    <trust:KeySize xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">256</trust:KeySize>
                                    <trust:KeyWrapAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p</trust:KeyWrapAlgorithm>
                                    <trust:EncryptWith xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptWith>
                                    <trust:SignWith xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1</trust:SignWith>
                                    <trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
                                    <trust:EncryptionAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
                                </trust:SecondaryParameters>
                            </tokenRequestParameters>
                        </message>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
            <ws2007HttpBinding>
                <binding name="">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="InheritedFromHost" />
                        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </ws2007HttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1785/Service1.svc" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="SomeService.IService1" name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <certificate encodedValue="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" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I tried to launch console application, but the error that valid issue should be specified has raised.
So I thought, that valid issue can be found in endpoints at Azure AD configuration page, and copied WS-Federation Single sign-on endpoint as an issuer.

Console program code is below.

```
var client = new SomeService.Service1Client();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "<valid user name>";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "<password>";
            client.GetData(10);
```

When I call service, I see in fiddler, that request is sent to WS-Fed endpoint but in response endpoint sends me html page with error

AADSTS20012: An error occurred when we tried to process a WS-Federation message. The message was invalid.

Could you please suggest me where I'm wrong and what to do to implement scenario I described in the beginning of the question?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WCF Rest Token based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553687/wcf-rest-token-based-authentication)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to obtain a token from Azure AD using username and password, see http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/.
However note that, as Brent highlighted, this is done via OAuth2 and not WS-Trust. You cannot use WCF machinery like createchannelwithissuedtoken or similar. In general, Azure AD and all of our modern libraries do not integrate with WCF and focus on Web API instead.
WCF integration is technically possible, but it requires VERY deep knowledge of WCF extensibility. If you have a chance of refactoring your services to use Web API, you'll find that everything will be much easier to do. 
HTH
V.

Comment: Thanks Vittorio for clarifying. @Oleg, yes we are talking software, so everything is possible and you could stich together a solution, but it would have multiple pieces as AAD does not have a WsTrust endpoint. Vittorio's advice will lead you to a solution that is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

If someone encounter this and has to connect to a WCF Webservice (are they considered legacy?) then [this source code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/bc3cba49af9c546d8cdf1faa185a7ba44daa996d/source/Clients/WcfClient/Program.cs) is a way to wrap the token into a SecurityToken.

There is also [a blog](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/02/give-your-wcf-security-architecture-a-makeover-with-identityserver3/) about it from Dominick Baier.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand you correctly that you want your WCF service to use tokens issued by Azure Active Directory as the identity: Thread.CurrentPrincipal? The WsFederation binding speaks wstrust and AAD doesn't. It looks like you are using a smart client, as opposed to a browser?  Is that correct?

AAD serves up identity tokens using: wsfederation and openidconnect both passive protocols.
AAD does serve up AccessTokens using OAuth.

However, both these will have a user consent / credential page. There is no way to pass credentials an obtain a token.

Comment: Brent, thank you.
But I still have a question.
If I got it correctly, then ADFS (talking about on premise AD) can serve me a token using uid/pwd passed in WCF ClientCredentials.
Since Azure AD expose AD federation endpoint I thought it would be able to do the same. 
Is that right?
Could you point me to the page declaring that AAD can't return a token by credetials, and user must login through AAD web page.?

Comment: WsFederation and WsTrust act differently.  With WsTrust, you send the credentials inside a RequestSecurityToken structure. With WsFederation, the endpoint asks for the credentials. This is the difference between Active and Passive. Have a look at the WsTrust and WsFederation specifications.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question here -

[**How I implemented AAD Token based Authentication in WCF Service using custom Message Inspector and Invoker**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67064744/6318505).

The way I implemented this is by using WCF extensibility. I wrote custom `Message Inspector` and `Custom Invoker` to do this. The message inspector extracts the token from authorization header and validates it and the custom invoker stops the invoking of the contract if the token is invalid.

Please refer to the above answer in the link for full implementation details. Apart from `Message Inspector` and `Custom Invoker`, there are few more classes that need to be added and some changes need to be done in web.config so as to integrate everything.