# WCF Rest Token based authentication - provide a full sample

Tags: authentication, wcf, openid-connect

It would be nice to have a full example for the solution which was descripe in second answer of [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553687/wcf-rest-token-based-authentication).
With the complete web.config and how can I access to the values of the jwt in the implemented wcf service.

Thanks for help

Ingo

I tryed to implement BearerTokenMessageInspector with all helper classes. I could build the solution an now I try to commissioning this solution. But it would be easier to have the full example.

Comment: May I ask why you're using WCF?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a token validation implemented with the certificate's encodevalue.

1.Generate the certificate locally

Visual Studio-tools-Command line-Developer PowerShell

Enter: **makecert -r -pe -n "CN=string" -ss TrustedPeople -sr LocalMachine -sky exchange**

[image]
2.Open MMC to view the certificate
[image]
3.Use Notepad++ to view encodevalue
[image]
4.Server configuration

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:8732/WcfAuthentications/Service1/"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" behaviorConfiguration="Service1Nehavior">
            <identity>
                <certificate encodedValue="MIIC8zCCAd+gAwIBAgIQiBrkayNb7L1Gt/k0O75GoTAJBgUrDgMCHQUAMBQxEjAQ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" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Service1Nehavior">
        <clientCredentials>
          <clientCertificate findValue="QiYouTest" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

As long as the certificate can be found in the client's place, it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. We implemented an restful Web Service with WCF. That Web Service is a wrapper for an old DCOM - Programm. Therefore we have to use that old technology. It would be very hard to implement an DCOM Client with .NET Core. 

Meanwhile is the sample programm running. 

Best regards Ingo

Comment: The example I provided is running on ASP.NET. Since Core WCF is new to this time and WCF technology is not so common, this example can be used a long time ago.